# multiple tabular environments using siunitx

Tags: enumerate, siunitx, article

Does anyone know of a way to create several decimal-aligned tables within an enumerate environment?  This is NOT a table, but it is a set of enumerated items with explanations and numerical data aligned on the decimal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item{blah blah blah:}
    \par 
        \begin{tabular}{l S}
                \hspace{10mm}blah blah blah blah:       &\$22,222.22 \\ 
                \hspace{10mm} blah blah blah:           &\$22,222.22 \\ 
        \end{tabular}

\item{blah blah blah:}
\par 
    \begin{tabular}{l S}
            \hspace{10mm} blah blah blah:       &\$22,222.22 \\
            \hspace{10mm} blah blah:            &\$22,222.22 \\
    \end{tabular}

\item{blah blah blah:}
\par    
    \begin{tabular}{l S}
            \hspace{10mm} blah blah blah blah:      &\$22,222.22 \\
            \hspace{10mm} blah blah blah:           &\$22,222.22 \\
    \end{tabular}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Well, it compiles. *What* is the problem?